# Using AceEditor: How to parse Acute( ` ) character and get code structure?

Tags: solidity, ace-editor

I am now developing a web site using React and it contains solidity code view panel.
The editor looks like the one on the below link.
https://ftmscan.com/address/0xce761d788df608bd21bdd59d6f4b54b2e27f25bb#contracts

I have implemented similar one using AceEditor which is available by installing react-ace, ace-builds modules.

Code is like this.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import AceEditor from "react-ace";

import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-java";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-language_tools";
import { code } from "./code";

function onChange(newValue) {
  console.log("change", newValue);
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <AceEditor
        theme="github"
        onChange={onChange}
        name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
        editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
        setOptions={{
          enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
          enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
          enableSnippets: true
        }}
        value={code}
        readOnly="true"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And I imported code from `code.tsx` file and error occurs when that code includes acute character.

My example code is on codesandbox and here is the link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-sun-0zj25?file=/src/index.js

I have 2 problems.

1. how to parse code that has acute( ` ) character inside?
   As you can see from my example code, parsing code is assigned to value props and should be wrapped by acute character and I can't resolve to wrap code that contains acute character inside.
2. As you can see [ftmstan site](https://ftmscan.com/address/0xce761d788df608bd21bdd59d6f4b54b2e27f25bb#contracts) I mentioned above, you can see outlined button on top right of code view panel and it shows structure of solidity code.
   And I can't understand how to get structure of code like that site.

Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: For what it's worth, `\`` U+0060 is a grave accent, not an acute accent.  Acute goes the other way: `´` U+00B4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ace website has instructions about creating or importing a new mode https://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter. You can use that with the syntax from vscode extension https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity/blob/master/syntaxes/solidity.json

Comment: Thanks @a user. I am new to ace-editor so not accustomed concepts of it.  I will try to create and import a new mode for solidity as you told. By the way, can you kindly tell me what this error means and how to fix it? The error message is like this.  "Unable to infer path to ace from script src, use ace.config.set('basePath', 'path') to enable dynamic loading of modes and themes or with webpack use ace/webpack-resolver" I am using React version 17.0.2 and Typescript.

Comment: I was able to resolve the error by adding ```import 'ace-builds/webpack-resolver'```

Comment: @a user, your answer was good to understand ace-editor. But what I wanna know is **NOT** ace-editor itself. I wanna know how to deal grave marks in solidity code. As I have to wrap solidity code with grave mark I do have to know how to wrap sol code with grave mark not changing sol code. At the moment I can only pass sol code after removing grave marks in the code. Secondly, plz let me know how to get code structure of sol file. Please try to click Outlined button on https://ftmscan.com/address/0xce761d788df608bd21bdd59d6f4b54b2e27f25bb#contracts page. It will makes it more clear what I want.

Comment: there is no simple way to get the outline, you'll need either a parser or some regexp that would match the common  syntax patterns. I do not know about solidity, you will have a better chance to get a useful answer if you separate your question related to sol from question related to ace, to get the attention of right people.